# How do i prevent duplicate entires based on multiple criteria

Tags: custom-list, validation, duplicate

How would I prevent duplicate entries into a list from being entered based on the status of a different item on the list. For example, I don't want someone to enter an new list item if they have an item with an open status.

> Name   Status
>   Jones, Open (new entry not allowed, duplicate value)
>   Jones, Closed (new entry is ok)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to deploy an **event receiver** and handle the event **ItemAdding**.

```
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    try
    {
        //statusOpen= your logic to check the status of a different item on the list
        if (statusOpen)
        {
            properties.Status = SPEventReceiverStatus.CancelWithError;
            properties.ErrorMessage = "Error status open";
        }
        else
        {
            base.ItemAdding(properties);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: or CSOM with PreSaveAction as other answer suggests

Comment: Out of interest, what does base.ItemAdding() actually do and why do you call it only if the event is not to be cancelled?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an Event Receiver and handle `ItemAdding` event.

Inside the handler you can add you validation logic. If it fails you can `Cancel` the update and take the user to a custom `Error` page.

Another option is to use `Client` object model and handle `PreSaveAction`.